# Split int64 Pandas column in two

Tags: python, pandas

I've been given a dataset that has dates as an integer using the format 52019 for May 2019. I've put it into a Pandas DataFrame, and I need to extract that date format into a month column and year column, but I can't figure out how to do that for an int64 datatype or how to handle it for the two digit months. So I want to take something like

```
ID    Date
1    22019
2    32019
3    52019
5    102019
```

and make it become

```
ID    Month    Year
1     2        2019
2     3        2019
3     5        2019
5     10       2019
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `//` and `%`

```
df['Month'], df['Year'] = df.Date//10000,df.Date%10000
df
Out[528]: 
   ID    Date  Month  Year
0   1   22019      2  2019
1   2   32019      3  2019
2   3   52019      5  2019
3   5  102019     10  2019
```

Answer (score 7):

#### `divmod`

```
df['Month'], df['Year'] = np.divmod(df.Date, 10000)

df

   ID    Date  Month  Year
0   1   22019      2  2019
1   2   32019      3  2019
2   3   52019      5  2019
3   5  102019     10  2019
```

---

Without mutating original dataframe using `assign`

```
df.assign(**dict(zip(['Month', 'Year'], np.divmod(df.Date, 10000))))

   ID    Date  Month  Year
0   1   22019      2  2019
1   2   32019      3  2019
2   3   52019      5  2019
3   5  102019     10  2019
```

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
s=pd.to_datetime(df.pop('Date'),format='%m%Y') #convert to datetime and pop deletes the col
df['Month'],df['Year']=s.dt.month,s.dt.year #extract month and year
print(df)
```

---

```
   ID  Month  Year
0   1      2  2019
1   2      3  2019
2   3      5  2019
3   5     10  2019
```

Answer (score 5):

`str.extract` can handle the tricky part of figuring out whether the Month has 1 or 2 digits.

```
(df['Date'].astype(str)
           .str.extract(r'^(?P<Month>\d{1,2})(?P<Year>\d{4})$')
           .astype(int))                              

   Month  Year
0      2  2019
1      3  2019
2      5  2019
3     10  2019
```

---

You may also use string slicing if it's guaranteed your numbers have only 5 or 6 digits (if not, use `str.extract` above):

```
u = df['Date'].astype(str)
df['Month'], df['Year'] = u.str[:-4], u.str[-4:]
df                                                                                                                    

   ID    Date Month  Year
0   1   22019     2  2019
1   2   32019     3  2019
2   3   52019     5  2019
3   5  102019    10  2019
```